# Maria db rpm Installation Error

Tags: centos, installation, mariadb

I am getting below error while trying to install Maria DB on centos

```
        [root@server1 MariaDB]# rpm -i MariaDB-5.5.30-centos6-x86_64-common.rpm
         warning: MariaDB-5.5.30-centos6-x86_64-common.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 1bb943db: NOKEY
       file /etc/my.cnf from install of MariaDB-common-5.5.30-1.x86_64 conflicts with        file from package mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64
       file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of MariaDB-common-5.5.30-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64
```

Comment: And what would you like help with? What do you understand the problem to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `rpm` and try installing it with `yum` instead as it tends to resolve conflicts automatically (and more sensibly). Try this:

```
yum -y install MariaDB-*.rpm
```

Edit: It might also be useful to run:

```
yum remove mysql-server mysql-libs mysql-devel mysql*
```

just for sanity sake.

Comment: It should not be necessary to disable all other repos when doing this, and it may cause the installation to fail.

Comment: Yeah, but I was just being overtly cautious. I have made the edit.